# Loading and using enum values in Ember

Tags: json, ember.js, enums

I have an Ember app consuming a rails based webservice.

On the Rails side, I have some enums, they are simply arrays.
Now, I would like to retreive those enums in the Ember app, and render them for select values.

The webservice returns a JSON response :

`get '/grades.json'`

`{"grades":["cp","ce1","ce2","cm1","cm2"]}`

On the Ember side, I created a GradesRoute like this :

```
App.GradesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return Em.$.getJSON('api/v1/grades.json')
    }
}));
```

Then, I think I need it in the controllers where these enums are in use:

```
App.StudentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['grades'],
    grades: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.grades')
}
));
```

So at least I thought I could iterate over the grades in the `students` template.

```
{{#each grade in grades}}
    {{grade}}
{{/each}}
```

But I get no output at all... debugging from the template and trying templateContext.get('grades').get('model') returns an empty array []

Any idea on how I could load and access this data ?

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up with ApplicationRoute, which is the immediate parent of StudentsRoute, so needs is relevant in this case.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
    Em.$.getJSON('api/v1/enums.json').then(function(data){
      controller.set('grades', data['grades']);
      controller.set('states', data['states']);
    }
  }
});
```

Now I can create an alias for each enums I need to use accross my app.

```
App.StudentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  needs: ['application'],
  grades: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.grades'),
  states: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.states')
});
```

I'm still not confident enough to be sure this is the way to go, any suggestion is welcome !

Comment: It's confusing that you switched to coffee script here.  You might want to update the question (or this) to match the syntax.

Comment: Sorry about that, my laziness ... I originally worked on this project using Emberscript, but went back to javascript, one of the reason being it's easier to share and discuss in places like here. So, Edit done.

Answer (score 0):

You just have some of your paths mixed up. In `StudentsController`, `controllers.grades` refers to the actual controller, not it's model. The following code should clear things up as it's a bit more explicit in naming.

```
App.StudentsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['grades'],
    gradesController: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.grades'),
    grades: Ember.computed.alias('gradesController.model.grades')
});
```

Also, be aware that using `needs` only works if your `grades` route is a direct parent of your `students` route. If it's not a direct parent, you won't get back the data you want.

Comment: Thank you. Though, as grades should be a shared resource between some other models, I think I'm on a wrong path. Setting the grades route as a parent for students does not make sense. I'll try to use the application controller to have control over grades.